# Firebase Authenticate Using Microsoft with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, azure, oauth

I am trying to authenticate with Microsoft using Javascript Firebase.

For starters, this is what my Javascript code looks like that is making the call:

```
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({...});
const auth = firebaseApp.auth();

auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
        .then(() => {
            var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
            provider.addScope('Xboxlive.signin');
            provider.addScope('Xboxlive.offline_access');
            auth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(errorCode + " " + errorMessage);
        });

auth.getRedirectResult()
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            // IdP data available in result.additionalUserInfo.profile.
            // ...

            // @type {firebase.auth.OAuthCredential}
            var credential = result.credential;

            // OAuth access and id tokens can also be retrieved:
            var accessToken = credential.accessToken;
            var idToken = credential.idToken;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(errorCode + " " + errorMessage);
        });
```

As for the Microsoft side, I created an account on Azure, went to the Active Directory and registered a new application.

I chose the "**Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)**" option, **Web**, and gave it the redirect URI provided by Firebase that looks like this: **https://my-firebase-app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler**

After creating it I went to the Certificates & secrets section of the app in Azure and created a client secret. I copied the secret value and pasted that into Firebase as well the Application Id.

With that information, I enabled Microsoft as a provider in Firebase.

Now when I go to sign in, I am currently getting this error in the auth.getRedirectResult method:

> auth/invalid-credential Firebase: Error getting access token from microsoft.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://my-firebase-app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_scope&error_description=AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter.
> Trace ID: f2d9bece-8803-40dd-a8e2-4adb23061400
> Correlation ID: 38828b39-f9c4-4553-a487-20552105cc71
> Timestamp: 2023-04-26 01:00:32Z&timestamp=2023-04-26 01:00:32Z&trace_id=f2d9bece-8803-40dd-a8e2-4adb23061400&correlation_id=38828b39-f9c4-4553-a487-20552105cc71, httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, crossOriginEmbedderPolicy=null, crossOriginOpenerPolicy=null, crossOriginResourcePolicy=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Any help would be awesome! Did I set up the Azure side right? The Firebase side right? Is the code correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding API permissions in your application related to **Microsoft Graph** and add them in your code like this `provider.addScope('User.Read');`.

Comment: So that worked. When I go to the API Permission section, I can see that the User.Read was already added. I am assuming why it worked. How can I add the Xbox scopes? When I click on Add Permission, I don't see anything Xbox related.

Comment: You can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1251517/where-is-the-xboxlive-scope-in-azure-ad-app) related to adding Xbox scopes.

Comment: What's odd is it says, "The Xbox live scope is a service scope that is already authorized in every client, but it requires manual authorization from the user if your app does not have an Xbox developer program partnership." So perhaps that's why I can't find it in a list? Because it's already authorized? But it still doesn't make sense since it is an invalid scope error.